# Specifying macro definitions via command line arguments to make4ht

Tags: definition, make4ht, command-line

I want to learn if there is a way to make `make4ht` pass some macro definitions to the LaTeX engine during compilation time. Let me explain what I am talking about with `pdflatex` as an example first.

I have a file named `foo.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello, \who{}
\end{document}
```

Now I can invoke `pdflatex` and specify the definition of `\who` in the command line arguments. This allows me to use the same source file `foo.tex` and build different output PDFs with different values of `\who`. Examples:

```
pdflatex "\def\who{world}\input{foo}"
pdflatex "\def\who{bob}\input{foo}"
```

Now with the same file `foo.tex` can I do something similar with `make4ht`? I guess what I am looking for is something like:

```
make4ht foo "<somehow specify \def\who{world}>"
```

Is this possible? If it is not possible, "no" will be a fine answer and I will then perhaps solve this problem by using a shell command like `sed` to replace the `\who` with what I need before every build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass additional definitions for LaTeX as the fifth argument to `make4ht`. Note that it needs to be properly escaped. This works for your example in Bash:

```
make4ht -m draft sample.tex "" "" "" '\\def\\who{world}'
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The following command worked for me: `make4ht foo.tex '' '' '' '\\def\\who{world}'`.

Comment: @LoneLearner I usually use the `-m draft ` option to get faster compilation, it is of course optional :)